# Use instance variable in "delete_if" method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am using 
`@registers.delete_if { |r| r.location_id != @location_id && @location_id.present?}`
to filter the registers so that only the ones with the chosen `location_id` are kept, if anything was chosen at least. The thing is that using the `@location_id.present?` works just fine but checking if the id's are the same doesn't. If I check hardcoded with a number like this: `r.location_id != 5` it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
@registers.delete_if { |r| r.location_id != @location_id.to_i && @location_id.present?}
```

But I think to do it better you should do it like :

```
@registers.delete_if { |r| r.location_id != @location_id.to_i if @location_id.present?}
```

Comment: Only possible after 10 minutes